# Compute descriptive statistics (mean, sd, n) by a group column across multiple columns using lapply and dplyr resulting in NA values

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have a Group column indicating group membership as well as many other columns containing numerical values. For each column containing numerical values, I want to get the Mean, Standard Deviation, and sample size for each subgroup.

Using the inbuilt iris dataset as an example, I have come up with the following code:

```
lapply(names(iris)[1:4], function(x) {
  iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(noquote(x), na.rm = T),
              sd = sd(noquote(x), na.rm = T),
              n = n())
})
```

However, the mean and standard deviation for each numerical column by group is a NA. R provides plenty of warning messages such as:

In mean.default(noquote(x), na.rm = T) :  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

In is.data.frame(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

However, I have ensured that my numerical columns have a numeric data type already.

I have also attempted using the `across` function, but the results are clearly wrong:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(1:4, ~ mean(., na.rm = T),
                   sd(., na.rm = T),
                   n()))
```

The number of/position of NAs in each numerical value columns in my actual dataset differs across numerical columns. The solution has to compute the mean/SD/sample size for each group using all the non-NA values for that particular column. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `across` is the correct approach you just need to fix the syntax.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(1:4, list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = T),
                               sd = ~sd(., na.rm = T),
                               Count = ~n())))

# A tibble: 3 x 13
#  Species    Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Length_sd Sepal.Length_Count Sepal.Width_mean
#  <fct>                  <dbl>           <dbl>              <int>            <dbl>
#1 setosa                  5.01           0.352                 50             3.43
#2 versicolor              5.94           0.516                 50             2.77
#3 virginica               6.59           0.636                 50             2.97
# … with 8 more variables: Sepal.Width_sd <dbl>, Sepal.Width_Count <int>,
#   Petal.Length_mean <dbl>, Petal.Length_sd <dbl>, Petal.Length_Count <int>,
#   Petal.Width_mean <dbl>, Petal.Width_sd <dbl>, Petal.Width_Count <int>
```

Maybe adding `pivot_longer` would make the output better -

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(1:4, list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = T),
                               sd = ~sd(., na.rm = T),
                               Count = ~n()))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Species, 
               names_to = c('name', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '_')

#  Species    name          mean    sd Count
#   <fct>      <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 setosa     Sepal.Length 5.01  0.352    50
# 2 setosa     Sepal.Width  3.43  0.379    50
# 3 setosa     Petal.Length 1.46  0.174    50
# 4 setosa     Petal.Width  0.246 0.105    50
# 5 versicolor Sepal.Length 5.94  0.516    50
# 6 versicolor Sepal.Width  2.77  0.314    50
# 7 versicolor Petal.Length 4.26  0.470    50
# 8 versicolor Petal.Width  1.33  0.198    50
# 9 virginica  Sepal.Length 6.59  0.636    50
#10 virginica  Sepal.Width  2.97  0.322    50
#11 virginica  Petal.Length 5.55  0.552    50
#12 virginica  Petal.Width  2.03  0.275    50
```